# What should be the Coercing input & output types for GraphQL Java custom Scalars?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

GraphQL Java Scalars: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/14.x/src/main/java/graphql/Scalars.java#L204

In all these cases the Coercing Input and Output types are the same.
For instance: `Coercing<Boolean, Boolean>`

Say, in-case I wanted to create a custom Scalar for DateTime. Should I implement it with  `Coercing<DateTime, DateTime>` OR `Coercing<DateTime, String>`?

Any insight on this will be helpful.